# Can we add any type of value in the list object?

Tags: c#, winforms, list

Can we add in the list object any type of value ?

Like if we

`List<string> str=new List<string>();`

then only string value can be added to list.But I want to add any type of value in the list like `string,decimal.`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Then you can use none generic type of List.
Use `ArrayList` or even you can use `List<object>`

Answer (score 0):

You can use the non generic equivalent of `List<T>` which is `System.Collections.ArrayList`.

```
var list = new System.Collections.ArrayList();
list.Add("test");
list.Add(1);
```

Or you could use `List<object>`.

Comment: Do **NOT** use ArrayList. Among other reasons, it does not work on Silverlight. Always use List<object> if you need a list that can hold anything. (However, it would probably be better to revisit the design decision which requires strings and numbers to be in the same list; that's a very, very bad code smell.)

Comment: could you  explain/provide a link for "Among other reasons"